# Sending datad to server without effecting UI thread in IOS

Tags: ios, api

I am making an ios app that needs to send data to server. But i want to use fastest way to send the data. I searched many ways. In android ratrofit is faster than volley and async request. So i want the same in ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) Library for Client Server communication.This will work on Async Operations without effecting UI.

Here is some of the good tutorials :

1. [Raywnderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)
2. [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/)

Comment: If answer finds helpful then please mark it as accepted. So other will find it helpful. Thanks